# OneToMany association using Foreign key in the OWNED entity

Tags: hibernate

I'm trying to build a OneToMany association between the conversation entity and the sms entity.

I want the foreign key to be on the conversation table.

```
Table_Conversation

- id BIGINT
- sms_id BIGINT FK REFERENCES SmsBean.id
```

Here is the Conversation class

```
public class Conversation{
  //...
  @OneToMany(targetEntity=SmsBean.class, table="conversation")
  public List getSmsList() {
    return smsList;
  }
}
```

Note that, I don't want conversation field in the Sms class as I don't need it.

Hibernate is not able to generate my tables and throws the following exception:

```
org.hibernate.cfg.NotYetImplementedException: Collections having FK in secondary table
```

I'm using Hibernate 3.5 / JPA2.0

Can you help figure out how to do this.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question which is mine, is incorrect.

I want the foreign key to be on the conversation table.

```
Table_Conversation

- id BIGINT
- sms_id BIGINT FK REFERENCES SmsBean.id
```

But what would happen when the same conversation(id=123) has two sms? This will lead to two rows with the same id.

```
Table_Conversation

|--------------|
| id  | sms_id |
|--------------|
| 123 |  1001  |
| 123 |  1002  |
|--------------|
```

So I abandoned this idea and now I'm using a join table as this the hibernate recommended way.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public class Conversation{
  //...
  @OneToMany
  public List<Sms> getSmsList() {
    return smsList;
  }
}
```

This will create a table Conversation_Sms which will hold the relationship.
If you added a Conversation field in the Sms entity and added a mappedBy attribute to the OneToMany annotation this table would not be created.. But like you said, this is not what you want..